# How To Add Certain Amount To a User Balance immediately a post is Added Succesfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

*I want User to be able to Earn from my website immediately they add a post on the website but am finding it difficult to add that feauture to my apps.
I want an amount to be added to my website immediately a post is submitted.*

> Please take a good look at my code*

**The Below code is for my post models.py.**

```
class Post(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=160, help_text='Maximum 160 Title characters.')
       summary = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text='Maximum text of 400 characters can be inserteed here alone' )
       subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
       introduction = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, 
       user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE))   
       content  = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)                           
      
       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
              self.slug = slugify(self.title)
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**This is a short code for my balance.py**

```
class Balance(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        balance = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

**Question Summary**

*I have a blog post where every users on the website is elligible to Post News and Information on the website and every user have a balance.
I Now want $2 to be added to this default balance of every Aunthenticated Users immediately a post is beeing added succesfully by a registered user.*

*That is if an aunthenticated user on my website add a post then an amount of $2 dollar will automatically be added to their balance  immediately they submit a succesful post on the Website and incase the user delete the post the $2 is minus from the balance immediately.*

*Can someone help me out with this code.*

What is the trick of making this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a post save signal:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete

def save_post(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        balance = instance.user.balance_set.all().first()
        balance.balance = F('balance') + 2
        balance.save()

def delete_post(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    balance = instance.user.balance_set.all().first()
    balance.balance = F('balance') - 2
    balance.save()

post_save.connect(save_post, sender=Post)
post_delete.connect(delete_post, sender=Post)
```

Comment: What if the user delete the Post or the poat is deleted for any reason. How do i remove the amount from the balance

Comment: You can similarly create a post_delete signal. Check the [Django documentation on signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/)

Comment: Thanks so much. Let me try and get back to you

Comment: I have edited my answer to give example of post_delete. Also one thing I would like to suggest in the Balance model instead of `user = models.ForeignKey(User)` try using `user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` as likely you want one user to only have one balance instance.

Comment: This is gotten sir and i will try it and get back to you shortly sir